# QLibrary resolve returns false

Tags: c++, qt

I´m trying to include classfiles dynamically right now and chose to do so by loading the .dll into a QLibrary. The problem I´m having now is, that when I try to call the resolve()-method it returns 0.

EDIT:
In the meantime the problem has been solved and I decided to edit the code, so others can see how it works:

**This is the .dll´s header file:**

```
#ifndef DIVFIXTURE_H
#define DIVFIXTURE_H

#include<QObject>
#include<QVariant>

class __declspec(dllexport) DivFixture : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE DivFixture();
    Q_INVOKABLE void setNumerator(QVariant num);
    Q_INVOKABLE void setDenominator(QVariant denom);
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant quotient();

private:
    double numerator, denominator;
};

#endif
```

**this is the dll´s .cpp-file:**

```
#include "testfixture.h"

DivFixture::DivFixture(){}

void DivFixture::setNumerator(QVariant num)
{
    numerator=num.toDouble();
}


void DivFixture::setDenominator(QVariant denom)
{
    denominator=denom.toDouble();
}


QVariant DivFixture::quotient()
{
    QVariant ret;
    ret=numerator/denominator;
    return ret;
}

//non-class function to return pointer to class
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DivFixture* create()
{
   return new DivFixture();
}
```

**And this is how I load my class:**

```
currentFixture.setFileName("C:\\somepath\\testFixture.dll");
if(currentFixture.load());
{
    typedef QObject* (*getCurrentFixture)();
    getCurrentFixture fixture=(getCurrentFixture)currentFixture.resolve("create");
    if (fixture)
    {
        Fixture=fixture();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to put extern "C" on c++ methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export your class using [__declspec(dllexport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
class __declspec(dllexport) DivFixture : public QObject
{
```

Comment: Seems logical, but that doesn´t seem to be the only problem. I´m still getting 'false'.

Comment: `currentFixture.setFileName(C:\\path);` should contain the name of the dll

Comment: actually it is:  
`currentFixture.setFileName("C:\\Dokumente und Einstellungen\\verhülsdonk\\Slim\\CustomFixtures\\testFixture.dll")`  
And the .dll gets loaded, so that´s not the problem.

Comment: From the documentation, only function are resolvable. A solution can be this : make your `DivFixture* create();` an extern "C" function, then use invokeMethod for your class functions

Comment: So do I just add the extern "C" in front of that method or do I have to take it out of the class declaration?

Comment: you need to take it out of the class and use extern "C"

Comment: If I do that, I´d have to store the returned DivFixture* in my main application, which is not possible.
See, I need to be able to include any class I want (because they aren´t written yet). So that create-method is kinda useless. my fault, sorry.

Comment: No, you can use QObject and call your class function with invokeMethod from QMetaType

Comment: Yeah, of course. that should work, thanks.
And I don´t quite know why, but the rest works too now.
Again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer isn't correct. `__declspec` has two possible parameters:

- dllexport
- dllimport

dllexport being used when compiling the library and dllimport when linking to it.

Qt already provides defines for that:

- Q_DECL_EXPORT
- Q_DECL_IMPORT

To make proper use of them, add something like:

```
#if defined(MYSHAREDLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

to a global header in your project that you will include in all classes you want to export. Then modify your classes so in the end the declaration looks like:

```
class MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT DivFixture : public QObject
```

A complete example and more information are given in the [Creating Shared Libraries](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html) of Qt's documentation.