# Why QLibrary cannot resolve a function if there is any QObject?

Tags: c++, c, qt

I have a library which exports one function as with `extern "C"` linkage.
I use Qt in the library, but if I make any class that derives from QObject, `QLibrary::resolve()` failes to resolve my exported function.
Using `nm -C path_to_lib`, I see it's there:

```
00000000000103a0 T GetMyPlugin
```

but `QLibrary::resolve()` still returns 0.
Only after I remove any of my classes that derive from QObject (and use moc) my symbol is successfully resolved.

So I wonder why does it keep on failing when the symbol is clearly there?

Comment: What is output of QLibrary::errorString()?

Comment: Did you see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671856/qlibrary-resolve-returns-false) Does that help?